# Spring 3.1: Getting the <mvc:resources To Work

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring.  I'm learning Spring 3.1.   I'm using the book "Spring In Action, 3rd ed..  I'm having trouble getting static resources found.  The book doesn't say much about it so I was wondering if I could get some help.

- The name of my application is "abc"
- The URL is something like "https://blah.blah.blah/abc
- I'm running "abc" on **WebLogic 9.2**
- I'm deploying "abc" as "abc.war"

The directory structure inside of my "abc.war" is

```
WEB-INF 
   classes
   lib
   web.xml
   webLogic.xml
   abc-servlet.xml
css
images
js
jsp
META-INF
```

In my web.xml  I have my dispatcher servlet defined like this:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

.....and this is the content of my abc-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.company.abc.controllers" />

  <mvc:resources mapping = "/**" location = "/"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/jsp/"/>
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

I've tried putting my static resources under a "resources" directory off of the root of my webapp, but that didn't make any difference ( I changed the tag to `<mvc:resources mapping = "/resources/**" location = "/resources"/>` when I did that ).

Basically, the abc webapp isn't finding any of the static resources.

It thinks the picture "header.png" is at

```
- htts://blah.blah.blah/images/header.png
```

So the image comes up blank, though when I paste this URL into a browser, I can get the image

```
- htts://blah.blah.blah/**abc**/images/header.png
```

I haven't found a way to get Spring to stick a "abc" into that url though.

I'm a brand new white belt with Spring, so baby talk in helping me figure this out with suggestions will not be taken as an insult :)

Thanks in advance for any help

Steve

Comment: I tried my set of files in Tomcat 6.  It works.  The problem is with WebLogic.  I found this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?102166-mvc-resources-and-war-on-Weblogic/page2).  Unfortunately, for a newbie like me, it doesn't seem clear if there is a workaround and one where I can keep deploying as a *war

Answer (score 0):

I tried my stuff in Tomcat 6 and all worked well ( this is not the first time something was harder in WebLogic, FWIW ).

I Google around and found this

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?102166-mvc-resources-and-war-on-Weblogic/page2

explaining that WebLogic and Spring 3.* have unresolved issues.

Being a newbie to Spring and WebLogic I didn't understand most of it.

I did notice that all of my static stuff would map to

- `https:/blah.blah.blah/abc/images/myimage.png`

But Spring would think it was

- `https:/blah.blah.blah/images/myimage.png`

So,

- I set my mvc tag to `<mvc:resources mapping = "/resources/**" location = "/resources"/>`
- Then in my new files that use spring I changed the paths to `../abc/images/myimage.png`

It all works.  The legacy files are still finding the static resources off of the root in the war with the paths in the legacy code AND the new Spring files ( I'm gradually converting abc from a Servlet webapp to a Spring webapp ) find them as ell.

Its a hack and its crude, but it gets me going for now

Comment: Reference your images using JSTL generated URLs to avoid relative paths and paths that hardcode the context root. `<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/myimage.png" />" />`.

Comment: Or just use the `<base href="/resources" />` element so you only have to do it in one place...